# Dielectric constant of Transition Metal Dichalcogenides (TMD)

Tags: electromagnetism, condensed-matter, dielectric

- Why is the in-plane dielectric constant of [transition metal
  dichalcogenides](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chalcogenide#Transition_metal_chalcogenides) larger than the out-of-plane dielectric constant? Is
  this because of the spacing between monolayers of the TMD?
- Why do these dielectric constants depend on the thickness and increase
  with increasing thickness?

Answer (score 2):

The dielectric constant, or more appropriately, the dielectric function, can be thought of as a measure of screening. A simple relation for which to picture this is:

$V_{eff} = V_{ext}/\epsilon$

Therefore, in TMDs, since the electrons are more mobile in the planes, they tend to screen potentials with a greater efficiency. This gives a higher dielectric constant.

Comment: If it is about screening, why it changes with thickness?

Comment: One would expect that the screening would change due to the presence of other layers.  I think that this should be intuitively plausible.